# Constantly getting this error SyntaxError class is a reserved identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, next.js

I am not able to find what is an error in this code
constantly I am getting this error
`SyntaxError class is a reserved identifier`

```
    import React from 'react';

class IconFilter extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <svg width='20' height='16' viewBox='0 0 20 16'>
        <path
          fillRule='evenodd'
          clipRule='evenodd'
          d='M1.5 5.75C1.5 6.439 2.061 7 2.75 7C3.439 7 4 6.439 4 5.75C4 5.061 3.439 4.5 2.75 4.5C2.061 4.5 1.5 5.061 1.5 5.75ZM3.5 0.75V3.117C4.65 3.446 5.5 4.495 5.5 5.75C5.5 7.005 4.65 8.054 3.5 8.383V15.25C3.5 15.664 3.164 16 2.75 16C2.336 16 2 15.664 2 15.25V8.383C0.85 8.054 0 7.005 0 5.75C0 4.495 0.85 3.446 2 3.117V0.75C2 0.336 2.336 0 2.75 0C3.164 0 3.5 0.336 3.5 0.75ZM9.75 11.5C9.061 11.5 8.5 10.939 8.5 10.25C8.5 9.561 9.061 9 9.75 9C10.439 9 11 9.561 11 10.25C11 10.939 10.439 11.5 9.75 11.5ZM10.5 7.617V0.75C10.5 0.336 10.164 0 9.75 0C9.336 0 9 0.336 9 0.75V7.617C7.85 7.946 7 8.995 7 10.25C7 11.505 7.85 12.554 9 12.883V15.25C9 15.664 9.336 16 9.75 16C10.164 16 10.5 15.664 10.5 15.25V12.883C11.65 12.554 12.5 11.505 12.5 10.25C12.5 8.995 11.65 7.946 10.5 7.617ZM16.75 7C16.061 7 15.5 6.439 15.5 5.75C15.5 5.061 16.061 4.5 16.75 4.5C17.439 4.5 18 5.061 18 5.75C18 6.439 17.439 7 16.75 7ZM17.5 3.117V0.75C17.5 0.336 17.164 0 16.75 0C16.336 0 16 0.336 16 0.75V3.117C14.85 3.446 14 4.495 14 5.75C14 7.005 14.85 8.054 16 8.383V15.25C16 15.664 16.336 16 16.75 16C17.164 16 17.5 15.664 17.5 15.25V8.383C18.65 8.054 19.5 7.005 19.5 5.75C19.5 4.495 18.65 3.446 17.5 3.117Z'
          fill='#555555'
        />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default IconFilter;
```

Comment: What line exactly does the error point to…?

Comment: maybe it is from another file, check you are using class in some html tag instead of className

Comment: it's is pointing to this line `export default IconFilter` @deceze

Comment: i have already checked this , @Joe's wiZa T
it is not creating this problem

Comment: try "export class IconFilter exte.."

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? Chances are it's an old one that's using a JS engine that hasn't implemented class

Comment: I guess it's Microsoft edge @phuzi

Comment: You're guessing it's MS Edge! I would have guessed it was more likely to be IE.

Comment: does this really solve this issue, because both are the same na?
try "export class IconFilter exte.. @Joe's wiZa T

Comment: actually some where else reported this error on sentry @phuzi

Comment: I'd first verify the browser version that caused the error and depending whether you want to support it implement something like Babel to convert modern ES to ES5 for those browsers.

Comment: Thanks For all the answer, I have successfully solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `class` is not implemented on the browser where the error is coming from.

Looking at https://caniuse.com/?search=class tells us this is likely to be IE (or Opera Mini).

Once you've figured out what browser (and version) is throwing the error you'll need to decide whether you'll support it.

If yes, you'll have to run your code through something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to create code that will work on these browsers.

Comment: Browser - Mozilla/5.0

Comment: @AmanAnku Is that from the useragent string? If so, it doesn't say which browser it is as pretty much every browser reports "Mozilla/5.0". You would need the full UA string to semi-reliably determine which browser is being used.